# How to get values of custom attribute in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get the value custom attribute that i have created as 'brands'

```
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description')); 


  foreach ($products as $product) {
    $p['products'][] = array(
            'id'        => $product->getId(),
            'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
            'name'      => $product->getName(),
        'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
          'weight'      => $product->getWeight(),
        'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
            'pirce'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,



        );
}
```

Comment: In your attribute selection code, you didn't select the custom attribute that you require.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below code

```
 $products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description','brands')); 


      foreach ($products as $product) {
        $p['products'][] = array(
                'id'        => $product->getId(),
                'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
                'name'      => $product->getName(),
            'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
              'weight'      => $product->getWeight(),
            'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
                'pirce'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,
              'brands' => $product->getBrands()        

            ); 

 }
```

You can also use

```
$product->getData('brands');
```

Comment: Its returning null value

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code for get attribute value:

> $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brands')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`